# Design different classes to calculate and print the sum of the following series (1/2)+(2/3)+(3/4)+(4/5)+(5/6)+..........+((n-1)/n)

Tags: java

i can't get this program:
Design different classes to calculate and print the sum of the following series:
        (1/2)+(2/3)+(3/4)+(4/5)+(5/6)+..........+((n-1)/n)
This is what i tried but can't get it:

```js
/**
 * Program to 
 * 
 * Anirudh Gupta
 * th August 2014
 */
import java.io.*;
class Program87a
{
   public static void main (String[]args) throws IOException
   {
        
        InputStreamReader isr=new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(isr);
        System.out.println("Enter the limit");
        int n=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        int i=1,j=2,sum=0;
        while(j<=n)
        {
            sum=sum+(i/j);
            System.out.println(sum);
            i++;
        }   
   }
}
```

thanks to everyone i got it.... NEVER ASSIGN ANYTHING INSIDE A LOOP!!!!

```js
/**
 * Program to 
 * 
 * Anirudh Gupta
 * th August 2014
 */
import java.io.*;
class Program87a
{
   public static void main (String[]args) throws IOException
   {
        
        InputStreamReader isr=new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(isr);
        System.out.println("Enter the limit");
        int n=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        double sum=0;
        double i=2;
        while(i<=n)
        {
            sum=sum+((i-1)/i);
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
   }
}
```

Comment: Dont think about it in terms of i and j, think about it in terms of i and i+1. While (i+1) < n, sum = sum (i/(i+1)) and increment i.

Comment: @zgc7009 it would even be easier to write the term as (n-1)/n: `while (n < limit) { sum += (n-1)/n;}`

Comment: @StephaneM true statement, same result :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't reset `i` and `j` inside the loop, since your loop will never end this way.

Change your loop to :

```
    i=1;
    j=2;
    while(j<=n)
    {
        sum=sum+(i/j);
        i++;
        j++;
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
```

You can make the code shorter :

```
    double i=2;
    while(i<=n)
    {
        sum=sum+((i-1)/i);
        i++;
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
```

Comment: Didn't work dude, plz help the loop keeps going and never ends, i checked my condition and its right....

Comment: @Anirudh The problem is not the condition. The problem is that you keep assigning i=1 and j=2 inside the loop.

Comment: ok, i just changed it but didn't work it still keeps going on

Comment: @Anirudh I tested the code and it terminates. Which value of n are you trying?

Comment: the value of n i'm trying is 5

Comment: @Anirudh Tried the fixed code with n=5 and got 2.716666666666667